# How do I rollback a transaction using Unit of Work and Repository patterns?

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactions, repository, unit-of-work

I have a user repository, which does all the user data access. I also have a unit of work class that manages the connection and transaction for my repositories. How do I effectively rollback a transaction on my unit of work class, if an error happens within my repository?

Create method on my UserRepository. I'm using Dapper for DataAccess.

```
try
{
    this.Connection.Execute("User_Create", parameters, this.Transaction, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Need to tell my unit of work to rollback the transaction.                
}
```

I pass both the connection and transaction that were created in my unit of work constructor to my repositories. Below is a property on my unit of work class.

```
public UserRepository UserRepository
{
    get
    {
        if (this._userRepository == null)
            this._userRepository = 
                new UserRepository(this._connection, this._transaction);
        return this._userRepository;
    }
}
```

I'm hoping to figure out the best approach.

*** Update ***
After doing more research into the unit of work pattern I think I am using it completely wrong in my example.

Comment: What was wrong in your approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dapper supports [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx), which provides a `Complete()` method to commit the transaction, if you don't call `Complete()` the transaction is aborted.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   //open connection, do your thing
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: If this is the TransactionScope of the .net framework it's not the right solution. SqlTransaction is the right way as it's more lightweight. Unless there's a compelling reason for using TransactionScope (which I don't see) I wouldn't advise using that

Comment: @thekip: There is no such thing as "right" or "wrong" solution; for you, lightweight might mean that it's the solution that fits *your* needs.  However, [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) solves the multi-object problem with a proper separation of concerns, something that is more of an issue nowadays (otherwise, you'll have to pass the [`SqlTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx]) through all of your layers and objects involved in the transaction, not very clean).

Comment: Having to pass your transaction through layers is a design flaw. If you implement a unit of work properly then you only have to start a transaction when you want to execute this unit of work. If you mix execution of the Unit of work with the concern of adding all operations to be executed that's where the problem is.